# Basic website that simply shows query string

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do the following: We need an easy way for user to find out what "id" their system has for remote support for example. I want to create a shortcut on everyone's desktop that leads to a website which then shows them their id with a query string (?id=..).

For example: the shortcut to *https://example.com/support/index.html?id=80085* should open up a website which then shows "**Your ID is 80085, please contact +1 123 456 for support or visit our online help page**"

I am able to do all of that in html except showing the id in the body of the website

Does anyone have an example how I could do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, basically I would create an HTML page with a simple `div` with an ID (for it to be found in script), and create a script that manipulates the url and places the corresponding text in the page.

```html
...
<body>
  <div id="main-div"></div>
  <script>
    const div = document.getElementById('main-div');
    const element = document.createElement('p');
    const id = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id');
    if (!id) {
      const emptyIdText = document.createTextNode('There was an error');
      element.appendChild(emptyIdText);
    } else {
      const idText = document.createTextNode('Your ID is ' + id + ', please contact +1 123 456 for support or visit our online help page');
      element.appendChild(idText);
    }
    div.appendChild(element);
  </script>
</body>
...
```

If you need, you can place this script in a `.js` file and import it via the `src` attribute of the script tag. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats perfect, does exactly what I want, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `id` parameter by converting the current url to a `URL` object in JavaScript like so

```js
// get the current url
const url = new URL(window.location.href)

// extract the id parameter from the url
const id = url.searchParams.get('id')

// print the results to the screen
console.log(`Your ID is ${id} please call ...`)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, where should I place this code? In the head or in the body? Should I Add <script type="text/javascript"> ..... </script>

Comment: @NilsL yeah this will go in a `<script>` tag, you will need to change `console.log` to something that outputs to the screen as well